# writing multiple lines back to a file, wrong file length

Tags: c

I want to get the a multiline text file's content, and put it back to the file.

However, I have an issue with the file length.
The null terminator (0) that I add is after some strange characters.

Something wrong with my f_length ?

Edit : If I set the line-endings of my file to Unix (LF), I don't have the issue. So it seems that my code is incompatible with Windows line endings. How can I account for Windows text files ?

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int f_length;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r+");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    f_length = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    buffer = malloc((f_length + 1) * sizeof(*buffer));      
    fread(buffer, f_length, 1, fp);
    buffer[f_length] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    fp = fopen(FILENAME, "w+");
    fputs(buffer, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: doing `fp = fopen(...)` a second time without first `fclose(fp);` looks troublesome, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: "*The null terminator (0) that I add is after some strange characters.*" Since the null terminator you add is after the contents of the file, that means there are some strange characters in the file contents. How would we know why the file has whatever contents it has?

Comment: No, strange characters still added.

Comment: The file as no strange characters.  Just normal lines text.

Comment: @trogne How did you determine that? Can you put the file someplace we can grab it so we can try to replicate your issue?

Comment: After the fread, the before contains extra characters.

Comment: @trogne Memory is going to contain all kinds of random junk outside of the bounds of what you've set to particular values. So what?

Comment: I found out something. If I set the line-endings of my file to Unix (LF), I don't have the issue. So it seems that my code above is incompatible with Windows line endings. How can I account for this ?

Comment: @trogne We have no way to replicate your issue, so we don't know what you're seeing or exactly what your issue is. Is it just a display issue or is the contents of your file somehow wrong at the byte level?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz , It's wrong at the bytelevel if line endings are Windows-style.  The file length I get is too large, so it creates a too large buffer, hence the strange characters.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including some typical input and some expected output and some actual output.  Then we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: pay attention to the returned value (which has type `ssize_t`) so you know how many characters were actually read when calling `fread()`

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  At a minimum it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Comment: OT: to avoid conversion problems, the declaration of `f_length` should be `size_t`

Comment: regarding: `buffer = malloc((f_length + 1) * sizeof(*buffer));`  the `sizeof(*buffer)` is not needed and just clutters the code with out adding any value.  Suggest removing that expression.   Also, when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` and/or `realloc()`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: when calling any C library function, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming the size of the file on disk is going to be equal to the number of bytes you will read. That is a valid assumption for a clean, binary file. It is not a valid assumption for a text file.

I'd suggest using the return value from `fread` instead of `f_length` as it reports the number of objects you actually read after any required read processing. You'll need to adjust your `fread` parameters to read 1-byte sized objects.

Comment: You got the parameters reversed. It should be `fread(buffer, 1, f_length, fp);`! (Updated answer.)

Comment: @trogne What do you mean by "buffer still too large" exactly? Does the output file look right?

Comment: Oh my mistake on this last comment. It works !  So the solution is to get the "fread" return value. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Use `fp = fopen(FILENAME, "rb+");` instead. For text files, you'll have newline characters replaced while reading (you've already noticed that in comments). In some cases, new format is shorter ("\r" or "\n" while the file itself contains "\r\n"), so f_length will be bigger than the actual data read.

Or you can use line-by-line reading functions, they are made for text-mode files.

Comment: Not working. With "rb+" I do not have strange characters, but I get extra new lines for every line. And the file becomes Mac style (CR), instead of Windows (CR+LF).

Comment: So the second option is for you. Use line-by-line reading functions with "r+", they also set null-term for you. I usually use fstream.getline(), but it's C++, not C, so choose one according to your taste :)

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
buffer[f_length] = 0;
```

This is placing the '0' way too far into the buffer.  this is why you see garbage characters.  Much better to capture the returned value from the call to `fread()` and set the '0' using:

```
buffer[ <returnedValue> ] = '\0';
```